# Is there a way to manually close an EXIFTOOL process that is stuck? Or perhaps force a Task.WhenAll to finish?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, process, exiftool

I am building an application that imports numerous video files from a file picker and runs them all through EXIFTOOL to get the metadata of each file.  A list of VideoFileModel is returned after all of the videos have been processed.  This all works great 99.99% of the time; however, I have come across one video file that halts execution of my application.  I am not sure if the video is corrupted or what.  It is the only one I have come across that provides this error but surely this will happen again one day so I need a fix.

When my application launches the process for EXIFTOOL for this video, the process window stays open and execution stops.  If I physical close the process window, the data is processed and execution continues with no errors.  It seems that the process is stuck.  Execution is halted because of the following await:

```
var metaDataResults = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(metaTasks);
```

My code after this relies of the data that is being returned to metaDataResults.  I have tried to kill the process manually with process.Kill() and process.Close() but the window stays open until I physically close it.  I have heard that there can result a “Dead Lock” in EXIFTOOL if standard output and standard error are both redirecting.  I am not redirecting standard error only output.  I have tested with standard error and is returns nothing.

Below is the code from initial button click:

```
private async void ImportVideoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {                    
        List<Task<Models.VideoFileModel>> metaTasks = new List<Task<VideoFileModel>>();
        
        foreach (string file in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            foreach (var video in _viewModel.AllLightningVideos)
            {
                if (file == video.VideoPath)
                {
                    video.VideoName = video.VideoName + "_";
                }
            }             
            metaTasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => _viewModel.ProcessMetaData(file)));
        }
        
        // EXECUTION STOPS AT THE CODE BELOW PRESUMMINGLY BECUASE THE PROCESS WILL NOT FINISH
        var metaDataResults = await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(metaTasks);
```

ProcessMetaData returns a VideoFileModel after calling the method getExifDataViaTool.  Below is the code for that method:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> getExifDataViaTool(string sourceFile, string parameters = "-a -api largefilesupport=1")
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    sourceFile = Regex.Replace(sourceFile, @"(\\*)" + "\"", @"$1\$0");
    sourceFile = Regex.Replace(sourceFile, @"^(.*\s.*?)(\\*)$", "\"$1$2$2\"");
    var argumentsString = parameters + " " + sourceFile;
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    string ExifToolPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "FFMPEG\\exiftool.exe");
    startInfo.FileName = ExifToolPath;
    startInfo.Arguments = argumentsString;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;            
    //startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();                 
    process.WaitForExit(1000);
    
    string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var pair = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
        if (pair.Length >= 2)
        {
            var key = pair[0].TrimEnd();
            var value = pair[1].TrimStart();
            result[key] = value;
            Debug.WriteLine(key + " : :" + value);
        }
    }            
    return result;            
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Interestingly, when I run a process for any other video, the process window appears and closes soon after.  For this one specific troubled video, the process window appears, closes soon after and another process window opens and stays open.

Comment: Have you tried to kill process?  `if (!process.WaitForExit(1000)) process.Kill();`